# Graph API won't return friends' religions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have a screen where users can select Facebook friends.  After submitting the form, I'm requesting a profile object from Facebook with specific fields (e.g.: `https://graph.facebook.com/some_id?fields=id,name,religion&access_token=xxx`).

When I request my own profile data with the `religion` field in the request, I'm seeing the value properly included with the result.  When I request my friends' profile data, the response is not including their religion even though I can see it when viewing their profile page directly.

I have made sure that I am requesting both `user_religion_politics` and `friends_religion_politics` permissions prior to making this call (and am using the updated access token).  What's going on?

Comment: Maybe your friends don’t share this info with apps their friend’s are using, i.e. they have turned it of in their security settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I get home, I'll set up a test account that has religion as public to see if it makes a difference when retrieving that test friend's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating two test user accounts, it appears that one of two things must be true in order to access a friend's religion via the Graph API:

1. The friend must make their religion info "Public".  Setting it to "Friends of Friends" for example is not enough to let it be retrieved by the API for some reason, regardless of our friendship.
2. The friend must authorize the app's `friends_religion_politics` permission.  By authorizing that permission on my own account, I am not telling Facebook that I want to allow access to my friend's religion info.  Instead, I am telling Facebook that I want to allow my own religion info for other friends who are requesting it via Graph API.

The second point is a very important distinction, and I wish it were spelled out in the documentation as such.  The permission is essentially worthless for my needs as is stands now, unfortunately.